# Using three options as arguments

Tags: perl

I was wondering what is the best way to check options with the following conditions:

- Only one of the options can be used.
- At least one of the options must be used.

If we speak about two options then it is easy (example in Perl):

```
if(defined($a) && defined($b)) {
    abort("Please use only one of the flags: a or b");
}

unless(defined($a) || defined($b)) {
    abort(1,"Please use a or b");
}
```

But for three options, it will be a little bit messy (too many ifs).
Is there any clean way to do so? If possible without using some extra operators like `xor` (only `if-else-unless`).

Comment: Note that `$a` and `$b` are special package variables when using `sort`, see [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). For this reason it is probably best to avoid using them for other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way Perl converts operator types to match the operand you can change the `if` statement to.

```
if((defined($a) + defined($b) + defined($c)) > 1) {
    abort("Please use only one of the flags: a, b or c");
}
```

Your `unless` statement can be extended like this

```
unless (defined($a) || defined($b) || defined($c) ) {
    abort(1,"Please use a, b or c");
}
```

However `unless` statements can get difficult to parse if you have more than one operand so take the opportunity to rewrite it to

```
if (! (defined($a) || defined($b) || defined($c) ) ) {
    abort(1,"Please use a, b or c");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

So you need to ensure that one and only one option is defined.

You can first count how many options are defined, using grep :

```
my $count_defined_options = grep { defined } $a, $b, $c;
```

Then you can check the value of $count_defined_options :

- 0 : abort because no option given
- 2 or more : abort because too many options given